# Gvim: Disable alt-letter behaviour inserting accented/unicode chatacters?

Tags: windows-7, vim, keyboard, gvim, unicode

I was using alt-j, alt-l, alt-i and alt-k to go to the beginning/end/top/bottom of the current line. Over the years I noticed there's so much stress on the alt key, so now I decided to go try other mappings. But since I'm so much used to my old mappings, I find myself constantly hitting alt-something in insert mode causing some unicode characters to appear, very annoying!

Is there anyway to disable those? i.e. nothing appears when I hit alt-letter.

Using Win7 x64, gvim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
:imap <M-j> <nop>
```

See:

```
:help <nop>
```

Answer (score 0):

In gvim, as you say you're using, if you `:set winaltkeys=yes` then alt key combinations are not mappable. If a menu with a given shortcut key exists it will activate the menu instead. Otherwise it will do nothing. You may need "m" in your guioptions option for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, it didn't do much in insert mode, I still see unicode characters when going alt-something. Even if it did work, I still use other alt combinations, like alt-c for clearing highlight search (nohlsearch)